# In Ruby, is there a way (a gem, perhaps) to process time in "XX:XX" format?

Tags: ruby, time

In particular, to add time (e.g. `11:40 + 00:30 = 12:10`) and check whether a time belongs to a range (e.g. `(11:00..12:00).include?(11:30)`).
I understand that I can write a class, but maybe a solution already exists.
The built-in `Time` class is not entirely what I want, because I am not interested in date-related features, which are built-in.

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: There's https://github.com/JackC/tod

Answer (score 5):

You can use `strftime` to format the time any way you want. If you want only the hour and minutes you can use this:

```
Time.now.strftime("%H:%M")
 => "08:57"
```

> time.strftime gives you all of these options to format

```
%a - The abbreviated weekday name (“Sun”)

%A - The full weekday name (“Sunday”)

%b - The abbreviated month name (“Jan”)

%B - The full month name (“January”)

%c - The preferred local date and time representation

%d - Day of the month (01..31)

%H - Hour of the day, 24-hour clock (00..23)

%I - Hour of the day, 12-hour clock (01..12)

%j - Day of the year (001..366)

%m - Month of the year (01..12)

%M - Minute of the hour (00..59)

%p - Meridian indicator (“AM” or “PM”)

%S - Second of the minute (00..60)

%U - Week number of the current year, starting with the first Sunday as the first day of the first week (00..53)

%W - Week number of the current year, starting with the first Monday as the firstday of the first week (00..53)

%w - Day of the week (Sunday is 0, 0..6)

%x - Preferred representation for the date alone, no time

%X - Preferred representation for the time alone, no date

%y - Year without a century (00..99)

%Y - Year with century

%Z - Time zone name

%% - Literal “%” character
```

Here is a link to the
[strftime](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/strftime) docs

> To check if time belongs to a certain range you can use the [cover](http://ruby-doc.org//core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F)
>   method

```
2.1.5 :003 > (Time.now..Time.now+10).cover?(Time.now)
 => true

2.1.5 :004 > (Time.now..Time.now+10).cover?(Time.now+20)
 => false
```

Comment: What about adding times and check whether a time belongs to a range?

Comment: Check the bottom part of my answer... You can use the cover method

Comment: `(Time.parse('11pm')..Time.parse('6am')).cover?(Time.parse('4am'))
=> false`

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: `cover` only works when you take the date part into account. For time-only values, it can give unexpected results, as shown in my example.

Comment: Yeah but if you can take DateTime value and format it to just the time it seems to work...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70755/discussion-between-joell-and-stefan).

Answer (score 3):

`ActiveSupport`'s Numeric will help you.

You can do:

```
require 'date'
require 'active_support/all'
DateTime.parse("11:40") + 30.minutes
```

You will need the `ActiveSupport` gem in your `Gemfile`.

As for checking if a time is in a range you can use [#cover](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F):

```
irb(main):001:0> (DateTime.parse("11:40")..DateTime.parse("11:50")).cover?(DateTime.parse("11:45"))
=> true
irb(main):002:0> (DateTime.parse("11:40")..DateTime.parse("11:50")).cover?(DateTime.parse("12:00"))
=> false
```

Comment: `(Time.parse('11pm')..Time.parse('6am')).cover?(Time.parse('4am'))
#=> false`

Comment: You need date information. How does it know that you are rolling over into tomorrow without it.

Comment: Exactly, but the OP is *"(...) not interested in date-related features"*

Comment: Then OP can't perform your calculation as it's ambiguous to what day 4am is on.

Comment: @Ash I see what you're saying, I think he wants it to implicitly assume that the second number in the range is the soonest possible time after the first in a `cycle` type day

Comment: Just like on a clock: the `4am` mark lies within the `11pm..6am` range. I'm aware that Ruby's `Time` class doesn't work this way, but I think this is what the OP is looking for.