# DateTime.now.strftime('Y%m%d%H%M%S') proper string format in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I'm trying to build a reference number for booking in Rails. I'm using

```
DateTime.now.strftime('Y%m%d%H%M%S')
```

for the reference number and concatenate some string. I used Sidekiq for performing this as a background job but then was confused with the result because it gave a different value in `strftime`.

```
def to_reserve
   venue = Venue.find(params[:id])
   venue_name = venue.name.delete(' ')
   reference_number = ReferencesNumberWorker.perform_in(5.seconds,    venue_name) 

   ................

end
```

Sidekiq:

```
class ReferencesNumberWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker

    def perform(venue_name)
        reference_number = DateTime.now.strftime('Y%m%d%H%M%S')
        return venue_name + reference_number
    end
end
```

This is a sample result:

```
HotelMatt67fb02cb5da7871f92347df9
```

which I didn't expect with the right result.

Comment: Besides you missed a leading percent sign in format, I can’t reproduce the problem here. And sidekiq is completely out of scope of this question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28455977/in-ruby-is-there-a-way-a-gem-perhaps-to-process-time-in-xxxx-format/28456279#28456279

Comment: @mudasobwa thank you. A typo error for the percent sign. I was expecting like this `NHOTEL20150821234318` which is I tried in rails console, I don't know why DateTime.now.strftime not giving the right format that's why I put the sidekiq for the question.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. You must have something that interferes with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's appending the hash for a Sidekiq job to your reference number where you are expecting it to append the return of the Sidekiq result.

So essentially this method

```
def to_reserve
   venue = Venue.find(params[:id])
   venue_name = venue.name.delete(' ')
   reference_number = ReferencesNumberWorker.perform_in(5.seconds,    venue_name)  <- This line will return Sidekiq job number, not the actual result from Sidekiq perform operation. 

   ................

end
```

When you define reference number you're assuming it'll give you the Sidekiq return, which it won't. This is the fundamental point of background jobs. You're disconnecting the Sidekiq job from what you're doing, i.e. offloading to a separate process. So you can't expect a return, you're offloading the method to Sidekiq. Sidekiq's return is basically the job number.

If you want this to work then move the reference number computation that you're doing to Sidekiq in the `to_reserve` method OR if it must be done in Sidekiq move all of the logic from `to_reserve` to Sidekiq's `perform` method.

Also note, to use Sidekiq you should pass (to Sidekiq) the object's id so you can relook it up in Sidekiq and perform some **idempotent** operation on the object. In my opinion, I don't think in this case you need to use Sidekiq. Its unnecessary complexity, but to each their own.

Sidenote: Prefer the Time class (`Time#now` vs. `DateTime#now`) over DateTime to compute the `strftime` method. Its a pure Ruby method and is faster than the DateTime class (a known performance bottleneck). Also your code won't have a hard dependency on Rails.

Comment: Ah! Okay. I get it. I already find a solution for this, I will not depend on time I used some uuid to build a unique reference id. thank you so much.

Comment: FWIW I wouldn't get too fancy with breaking rails default Integer as the id convention. That way lies madness as you'll be writing a lot of code to "fix" the built in association methods and you're adding a lot of slowdown to your database lookups with 36 char sting lookup vs Integer lookup. I doubt the advantages of GUID outweigh these two simple issues. Good Luck with your project!